# An attempted to execute remote call was declided, because current mode is 'off'

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.1

I got 404 when Sitecore tries to use it's own web-api.

the url is

```
/-/item/v1?sc_itemid=%7B11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111%7D&scope=c&sc_database=master
```

when I check the logs i got the following info

```
INFO  [Item Web API] An attempted to execute remote call was declided, because current mode is 'off'.
```

does any one know how can I turn it on? all of itemwebapi.mode values in config is set to `StandardSecurity`

---

It started to happen when we upgraded our Sitecore website from 6.5 to 7.1.
I installed the fresh Sitecore 7.1 and it doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we found the Answer of our problem after comparing the configs of freshly installed sitecore with our upgraded site.
in Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Config there is a patch to add  sitecore.ItemWebApi after Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SiteResolver and we have our custom dll so it couldn't find it!

```
<processor type="Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SetRuntimeSettings, Sitecore.ItemWebApi" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SiteResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
```

Comment: Had the same issue. A solution would be to configure the pipeline overrides in a file that comes after the sitecore config files. We first had pipelines.config, which comes before sitecore_*.config. After renaming it to xxx_pipelines.config (sorted after sitecore_*.config), the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 4):

can you check please next configuration file : 
    \Website\App_Config\Include\Sitecore.ItemWebApi.config

This is default configuration

```
  <site name="website">
    <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.mode">Off</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.access">ReadOnly</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess">false</patch:attribute>
  </site>
```

I also received your error, I change it from Off to StandardSecurity and works fine .